# Ostream << operator overloading and it's return type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I learnt how to do operator overloading of Stream Insertion Operator. But one doubt remains.

```
#include<iostream>

class INT
{
    int i;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,INT&);
public:
    INT():i(100){}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& obj,INT & data)
{
   obj<<data.i;
   return obj;
}

int main()
{
    INT obj;
    std::cout<<obj;
}
```

What significance `return obj;` has?

Do that **return** have any use further?

Are We forced to do that **return** because of the syntax of the operator<< without any usefulness?

Comment: Think of what happens here: `cout << a << b << c;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember how you can write code like this:

```
cout << "The data is: " << somedata << endl;
```

This is actually the same as:

```
((cout << "The data is: ") << somedata) << endl;
```

For this to work, the `<<` operator has to return the stream.